# nginx incorrectly matches regex

Tags: nginx, regex

I have the following block in nginx.conf:

```
server {
    listen 9001;
    # Only forward matching URLs for the public facing port
    location ~ ^/challenge/1.0/auth/complete/[A-Z0-9]+$ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5001;
        proxy_connect_timeout 300s;
        proxy_read_timeout 300s;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
```

But nginx incorrectly matches and allows these urls:

```
http://localhost:9001/challenge/1.0/auth/complete/x
http://localhost:9001/challenge/1.0/auth/complete/A.
http://localhost:9001/challenge/1.0/auth/complete/,
```

Any idea why?
Thanks.

Comment: How did you check? Show full config

Answer (score 0):

Nginx (as of version 1.11.9) doesn't match the urls you provided when the first `location` in the `server` block is set to:

```
location ~ ^/challenge/1.0/auth/complete/[A-Z0-9]+$
{
    return 403;
    break;
}
```

Please adjust your config to match example above (i.e. place this right after `server` block starts and add `break` directive).

Comment: I **do** want to match that regex and **allow** them. Your example will return 403 which is not what I want. nginx should have rejected the urls I listed.

Comment: @ThiagarajanHariharan Obviously you'd have to replace `return 403`, which I included just for example with whatever you want. Edit your question and add your full `server` section if unsure, I'll update my answer accordingly. And yes, this doesn't match the urls you had listed (meaning it doesn't do `return 403` on them)

Comment: I have posted the server block. To repeat, I want to only match the regex in the location directive. Anything that does not match I want nginx to return error to the client.

Comment: The closing } was missing for the server block. It works now. Sorry for the trouble. Thanks @Anubioz for taking the time to respond.